# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.LoggerSettings com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.getLoggerSettings()'

Tags: mongodb

i am running a jar file and it is throwing error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.LoggerSettings com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.getLoggerSettings()'
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients.createCluster(MongoClients.java:150)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients.createMongoClient(MongoClients.java:139)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients.createWithAsynchronousSocketChannel(MongoClients.java:175)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:116)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:87)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:62)
    at com.mongo.clients.MongoDBReactiveApp.dbActions(MongoDBReactiveApp.java:32)
    at com.mongo.clients.MongoDBReactiveApp.start(MongoDBReactiveApp.java:18)
    at com.mongo.MongoApplication.start(MongoApplication.java:49)
    at com.mongo.MongoApplication.main(MongoApplication.java:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

**build.gradle file have following setting**.

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.12.10'
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-async', version: '3.12.10'
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-reactivestreams', version: '4.5.1'
    implementation group: 'args4j', name: 'args4j', version: '2.33'
//  implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-core', version: '4.3.4'
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'bson', version: '4.5.1'
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-sync', version: '4.5.1'
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-core', version: '4.5.1'
    implementation 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3'
    
}
```

i tried with multiple version of mongo-java-driver but it didn't worked.
also use builder class

Comment: Why you need multiple versions?

Comment: Might be getLoggerSetting() is not supported

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this exact error because I was using two different versions for `mongodb-driver-sync` and `mongodb-driver-core`.

I was able to spot this by running `mvn dependency:tree` (in gradle it should be `gradle dependencies`) in the project root and see that one of them was set to `4.8.2` and the other `4.9.1`.

I fixed it by declaring these two dependencies explicitly with version 4.9.1 in my pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I see that your build.gradle specifies the same version for both these modules but still:

- I advise you to run `gradle dependencies` and confirm that you are indeed using 4.5.1 for both dependencies
- Both `mongo-java-driver` and `mongodb-driver-async` are unmaintained [image: you should use the third one]